# Script to switch from plain to multi coloured needed - if it's even possible?

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a website update for a charity (status pending) to provide support for learning difficulties for both children and adults, as well as their family and friends.

The learning difficulties are associated with Auditory Processing Disorder, Visual Processing Disorder and so on. These LD's encompass Dyslexia, Disgraphia, etc.

Anyway, I need to create a button that will change the option of viewing the text either as I've written it here (plain black on white bg) or to this link:

[apduk site](http://apduk.org.uk/)

I will be using joomla, and I think this can be done with a javascript, but my basic javascript knowledge is long gone - any ideas or tips on how to achieve this, perhaps so that I could change the available colours in the script to suite various LD's would be very much appreciated.

Many thanks in advance,

Steve

Comment: There is no magic button to do this. You will have to write code for this and you can start by showing us what you have tried.

Comment: I've tried nothing - haven't a clue where to start. I know it needs to be created from scratch but I wanted to find out if anyone had already done this or something like it I could just edit, etc.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/A52Lj/

Comment: I have made a development on this and if you are interested, please follow this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20843423/need-to-control-a-plugin-from-front-end-to-apply-to-article-text-only-is-this)

Answer (score 1):

You basically want to switch your stylesheet for another.

If you google stylesheet switcher there is quite al ot of info about how to do this. Here is an example from my quick search:

http://www.cssnewbie.com/simple-jquery-stylesheet-switcher/#.Uox7omRmWPU

Or even if you search SO there are a few questions that relate to this:

[Style Switcher & Text Resizer Combined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612016/style-switcher-text-resizer-combined)

Comment: My problem with that is the stylesheet the joomla template uses comes with the template, so changing the stylesheet will make it difficult to change the template, won't it? I searched through the site before posting to find anything relating to what I want to do, but I would never have guessed that changing the stylesheet would acheive my goal as I don;t think it can be done if using a joomla template. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: if you duplicate the joomla stylesheet and edit that then you shouldn't have a problem - you will only really be changing colors etc.

Comment: There in lies the rub - what if they decide to change the joomla template, it will not display correctly or the function to change the text will not work properly, unless I store this stylesheet somewhere else other than in the same folder as the template's stylesheet?

Comment: who is changing the template? the user or the client? There are limitations to everything unfortunately.

Comment: I'm changing the template via the joomla gui control panel. Also, other admins have the rights to change the template. Point being, can a solution to this problem be accomplished any other way?

Comment: tell them not to change it - or create another stylesheet for each temaplte

Comment: That's going to be a problem, as it's essential they can change it. There must be another way to accomplish my goal to change the text's colour every 5th word, etc.